Radius Authentication using REST API Call
Refer this https://github.com/kabbo06/radius_auth_using_api
I want to Authentication using Rest API Call and I need to set attribute (for example, Session-Timeout) for each user from API.
How to do it?
I try to ask solution from ChatGPT, but it is not work. It look like some thing went wrong on condition reply:Profile == "admin"
This is what I try.
API service
USER_DATA = {
    'user1': {
        'password': 'pass1',
        'profile': 'admin'
    },
    'user2': {
        'password': 'pass2',
        'profile': 'guest'
    }
}

@app.route('/authenticate', methods=['POST'])
def authenticate_user():
    data = request.get_json()
    username = data['username']
    password = data['password']

    # Verify the Authorization token
    auth_header = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    if auth_header != f"Bearer {SECRET_TOKEN}":
        return Response(
            "Invalid token!",
            status=403,
        )

    # Authentication logic with profile
    user = USER_DATA.get(username)
    if user and user['password'] == password:
        response = {
            'authenticated': 'ok',
            'profile': user['profile']
        }
        return jsonify(response)
    else:
        return Response(
            "Authentication Not Allowed!",
            status=400,
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)

mods-enabled/rest
connect_uri = "http://192.168.56.106:5000"

authenticate {
    uri = "${..connect_uri}/authenticate"
    method = "post"
    request_headers {
        Content-Type = "application/json"
        Authorization = "Bearer my-hardcoded-token"
    }
    body = json
    data = '{ "username": "%{User-Name}", "password": "%{User-Password}" }'
    force_to = json
    return {
        ok = {
            update {
                &reply: += "Profile := %{json:profile}"
            }
        }
    }
}

sites-available/default
authorize {
    ...
    if (reply:Profile == "admin") {
        update reply {
            Filter-Id := "admin-filter"
            Session-Timeout := 3600
        }
    }
    elsif (reply:Profile == "guest") {
        update reply {
            Filter-Id := "guest-filter"
            Session-Timeout := 1800
        }
    }
    ...
}

